# react-google-login not woking on react-web-view

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview, google-authentication

I have an issue when login with google in web-view react native but it works in the website

```
<WebView
userAgent="Chrome/56.0.0.0 Mobile" 
ref={this.WEBVIEW_REF}
onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange.bind(this)}
  source={{
    uri: 'https://siteweb.com'
  }}
  style={{ marginTop: 15 }}
  onLoad={() => this.hideSpinner()}
  onError={()=>alert("Something went wrong !! ( check your netinfo )")}
/>
```

Itry to add userAgent like other people said but it still not working ...

Comment: do you want to implement google login in you react native app?

Comment: yes but I have just web-view  for now in my react-native app

Comment: You can use *googlesign* npm package for it !

Comment: i'm using react-google-login on my website so I can't use on other library on my react-native app

Comment: Did you managed to solve this?

Comment: Noo I didn't ..